# iOS React Native fetch with redirect to custom url scheme fails with `Network request failed` error

Tags: ios, react-native, xmlhttprequest, fetch

On my current react native project we have the authentication flow build on top of oidc.
It uses multiple redirects while performing user authentication.
These redirects are made to urls which bear some authentication data in it.
Here's some stub example:

```
fetch('https://my-auth-server.domain/address') -> 302 ('myappid://action?user=data')
```

As you can see the server redirects initial request to custom url scheme. And there's the issue:
(I suppose) Because of this custom url scheme I do not receive response, but only "unsupported URL" XHR error. No headers, from which I could parse redirect location, nothing. Just this error text.

Is it really possible to handle custom url scheme redirects via React Native fetch / XHR?

**Environment:**

- React Native 0.64
- iOS 12.1-14.4
- React Navigation v4
- XCode 12.5

**What I've already did:**

- I have deep linking set up in app with URL Schemes set.
- I have `Allow Arbitrary Loads` set to true with domains configured.
- I tried to use pure XHR request, axios, fetch - the result is always the same.
- In simulator's Safari and in desktop browser initial url opens just fine.
- React Flipper also shows response from this request with all data! (status: 302, all headers in place, etc.)

There's also no possible way to intercept this redirect, since React Native's fetch does not support *{ redirect:  "manual" }* option.

Comment: Bummer, I'm having the same issue.

Comment: A complete bummer, I am more than agree with you. The only possible solution I am looking at is to use WebView for handling this auth chain. But the whole purpose of this changes I am making was to move away from using WebView >.<

Comment: I'm looking to run a backend server to do the authentication behind the scene. If you like, we can discuss offline and post what we're doing here as an answer if successful.

Comment: It seems also like possible solution. You can reach me via email tollemet@gmail.com for futher discussion.

Answer (score 0):

iOS's URLSession doesn't know how to handle your custom url schema. RN throws a network error but if you debug this using xcode you will see more info, like this:
`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"`.
You need to write your own handler for your custom schema (`myappid://action?user=data`).
Helpful topics:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656308 - first comment
[Custom URI Scheme "Unsupported URL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392359/custom-uri-scheme-unsupported-url)
[Unsupported URL when app receives a redirect to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172935/unsupported-url-when-app-receives-a-redirect-to-itself)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).